# Strict Ajax Live Data Search Results

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, livesearch

Currently i am looking for a Solution of my problem.
Iam doing some work for a Community but my Coding Knowledge is very low.
So i came around with this Search Template:
https://www.webslesson.info/2016/03/ajax-live-data-search-using-jquery-php-mysql.html
So far the search is working ok. But the Posted searches are not the way i want it.

I tried to switch the LIKE query to =
But then the search results in No Data Found.
I searched around the net to find a solution, but my english and my progam language knowledge is not that good (maybe i searched for wrong words)
I also though about some Normalizing the Database, but cannot find a good solution.

I think the critical part of my problem is the query as it is with LIKE

```
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
  WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR Address LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR City LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR PostalCode LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR Country LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
```

so i need to change it to = but that dosnt work. I readed about some regex, but cannot get that done, as my knowledge is that bad.

I need the search to be strict. If i search for 5, then it only should show results with 5. Not with 15, 25 and so on.
https://ni2984357-1.web06.nitrado.hosting/New/ here you can try what i mean. if it is needed, because i dont know how much code you need.

Comment: Could you add a comparsin between current and expected output please?

Comment: oh oversaw your reply. need to get inside this structure here :) Currently i search for 5. Output: Alpaka 3, 7, 9, 10, 15, 20, 22 20, 77, 90 10, 15, 20, 60, 90 (the output is because of the 15 in the first and 3. chest. So in the end i would like to have it that this line wont shown because i only searched for 5 not 15. That happens with all the numbers. Sorry cannot tell it better because my english is so bad